# How to implement nested filters in diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm quite new to Rust and Diesel. I'm now trying to implement Diesel filtering for query like this:

```sql
-- @param1 is duration in years
-- @param2 is duration in months

SELECT columns FROM a
WHERE 
(...dynamic AND clauses)
AND (((a.min_unit = "Years") AND (a.min_duration <= @param1))
  OR ((a.min_unit = "Months") AND (a.min_duration <= @param2)))
(...dynamic AND clauses)
```

After some searches in docs and around the web, I still couldn't find how to do this.
My closest guess is:

```rust
let param1 = ...;
let param2 = ...;

let mut query = a::table.select(a::all_columns).into_boxed();
// dynamic clauses: query = query.filter(...) ...
query = query.filter(a::min_unit.eq(Some("Years")).and(a::min_duration.le(Some(param1))))
  .or_filter(a::min_unit.eq(Some("Months")).and(a::min_duration.le(Some(param2))));
// dynamic clauses: query = query.filter(...) ...

let results = a::table.load<A>(&*conn);
```

Anyone has idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is my latest try:

```rust
let min_months_predicate = a::min_unit.eq(Some("Months"))
    .and(a::min_duration.le(Some(param1)));
let min_years_predicate = a::min_unit.eq(Some("Years"))
    .and(a::min_duration.le(Some(param1)));

query = query.filter(min_months_predicate.or(min_years_predicate))
    .filter(a::max_duration.ge(Some(param2)));

debug!("TEST QUERY: {:?}", debug_query(&query));
```

which yields this query:

```
"SELECT \"a\".\"id\", \"a\".\"code\", .... WHERE (\"a\".\"min_unit\" = $1 AND \"a\".\"min_duration\" <= $2 OR \"a\".\"min_unit\" = $3 AND \"a\".\"min_duration\" <= $4) AND \"a\".\"max_duration\" >= $5"
```

And when I use sql EXPLAIN with this query, I got this clause:

```
  Filter: ((max_duration >= 60) AND (((min_unit = 'Months'::text) AND (min_duration <= 3)) OR ((min_unit = 'Years'::text) AND (min_duration <= 5))))
```

which seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually looks correct (I haven't run it). The documentation here points to how it is done: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.or_filter `foo.filter(bar).or_filter(baz) is like foo.filter(bar.or(baz))` but the second one is "nested". So, to get
`(id = 5 OR other = 6) AND foo=7`
one would do
`.filter(id.eq(5).or(other.eq(6))).filter(foo.eq(7))`.
Hope that helps!